# Facing issues with sending jquery variable data to php session or variable on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

This might seem repeated but I am still not understanding the correct way for sending the data in my jquery variable to my php session or variable.

I saw that it is done using ajax but I am still not able to implement it in my code.

Here is the jquery code which currently does nothing other than displaying value on the same html page:

```
$(document).on("click","button",function(){
    var clicked_name = $(this).html();
    var url = window.location.href;
    var params = url.split('?id=');
    var id = (params[1]);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"slider.php",
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(){
            $('#user_names').html(clicked_name);
        }
    });
});
```

And this is where it is displaying:

```
    <div id="user_names"></div>

<?php
    $fetching_clicked_user_name = $_POST['user_names'];
    echo $fetching_clicked_user_name;
?>
```

**Now I don't want to display the value on the page, rather than that I want to send that value to the php session or variable in the same file.**

If you don't understand my question then do ask and please explain the solution in simple terms as possible as I am new to ajax and all this stuff and still learning this.

Comment: `I saw that it is done using ajax but I am still not able to implement it in my code.` You're correct in that AJAX is what you need to use, but to help you we need you to show us what you tried.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I understand that I need to show you the code, I didn't have it locally and was on the server and here it is.
`$(document).on("click","button",function(){
        var clicked_name = $(this).html();
        var url = window.location.href;
        var params = url.split('?id=');
        var id = (params[1]);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"slider.php",
            data:{id:id},
            success:function(){
                $('#user_names').html(clicked_name);
            }
        });
    });`

and this is the rest

Comment: ok let me edit the question itself

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have edited the question and included the code, can you help me now. I really want to know and I am trying this for days still not able to grasp it as I am new to ajax and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing respective lines in your code to the following

```
data:{user_names:id},
success:function( result ){
    $('#user_names').html( result );
```